# Need Help Initializing a Generic Property in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, generics, nullreferenceexception

I've created a request class. Here is an abbreviated version of it:

```
Public Class Request(Of T)
    Private _Account As String
    Public Property Account() As String
        Get
            Return _Account
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Account = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _InnerRequest As T
    Public Property InnerRequest() As T
        Get
            Return Me._InnerRequest
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As T)
            Me._InnerRequest = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And then I have two other classes that I intend to use with this one - again, abbreviated

```
Public Class Individual
    Public FirstName As String
    Public LastName As String
    Friend Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And

```
Public Class Commercial
    Public EntityName As String
    Friend Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Again, both of these are pretty abbreviated.  The issue comes in when I attempt to use the properties of individual or commercial:

```
Dim Req As New Request(Of Individual)()
Req.InnerRequest.FirstName = "Herman"  <-- Null Ref Exception
```

So... how do I get my inner request null ref exception kicked?  I tried simply using `Me._InnerRequest = New T` in the New sub of Request, but no dice.  Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: Unless you're using a pretty old version of .Net Framework, you don't need all of the `_BackingFields` and `Get`s/`Set`s if you are just using default getters and setters.  And @Barry is right.  `Req.InnerRequest` never gets set, so it is null.

Comment: There's a little more going on there than what I've put up here, so it's not quite default.  I wasn't aware that I didn't need the backing fields, when I initially set up properties it's just "pro" tab tab and everything is populated for me, then I make my tweaks.  I'll look into simplifying.  Barry's suggestion doesn't instantiate it when the Request object is created which is ideally what I'm looking for, but may not be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Req.InnerRequest must be set to an object instance of Individual first.

```
Req.InnerRequest = new Individual()
Req.InnerRequest.FirstName = "Herman"
```

Or create an instance for InnerRequest with the following modifications

```
Public Class Request(Of T As {New}) 'Classes of type T must have a public new constructor defined
::
Private _InnerRequest As New T() 'Creates a new class of type T when an instance is created of Request
```

And make the constructors of the other classes `Public` instead of `Friend`.

Than you can directly do

```
Dim Req As New Request(Of Individual)()
Req.InnerRequest.FirstName = "Herman"
```

Comment: Ahh... I was working on a reply and you edited.  Your second suggestion got what I was looking for.  I couldn't create a new individual from the calling code because it was outside of the assembly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

@Barry already answered what the main problem is, but here's an alternate syntax if you prefer object initializers:

```
Req.InnerRequest = new Individual() With { FirstName = "Herman" }
```

Or, if you prefer, you could overload the constructor for your `Individual` class:

```
Dim individual As New Individual("Herman")
Req.InnerRequest = individual
```

With the `Individual` class looking like:

```
Public Class Individual
    Public FirstName As String
    Public LastName As String

    Friend Sub New()
    End Sub

    Friend Sub New(firstName As String)
        Me.FirstName = firstName
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the alternate syntax you proposed.  Barry ultimately got my question answered, but this is very useful to know as well.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You probably should consider restricting the T to some `Entity` class:

```
Public Class Request(Of T As Entity)
```

From which both Individual and Commercial will inherit:

```
Public Class Individual : Inherits Entity
```

Then maybe declare an overridable property Name of type String on this Entity class (which can be abstract/MustInherit), this should provide some flexibility. Otherwise you'd be having a hard time consuming your design pattern.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing.  Or at least restrict it to something that implements an interface.  `IRequestable` has a nice ring to it, haha.

Comment: I'm going to try this out as well.  This is another interesting idea I hadn't considered - but it may be more convenient to add new types for the InnerRequest in the future with the method I'm currently using.  Still, a very interesting idea.  Thank you!